# A 'typedef' for a template function (boost::make_shared)

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11

I'm migrating my project to C++11 and I'm trying to use as much of standard library as possible.

Before I finalise the migration, I need a quick way to flip between boost and STL implementation of `shared_ptr` (to do benchmarks, unit tests etc).

So I defined an alias for `shared_ptr` like this:

```
#ifdef _USE_BOOST_
template <class C>
using shared_ptr = boost::shared_ptr<C>
#else
template <class C>
using shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<C>
#endif
```

now I need to do the same for `make_shared`... But how? Macro? A wrapper? I don't really like either of them. What are the alternatives?

Comment: You don't have much choice but to write a quick wrapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using variadic templates and perfect forwarding:

```
template<typename C, typename...Args>
shared_ptr<C> make_shared(Args &&...args) {
#ifdef _USE_BOOST_
  return boost::make_shared<C>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
#else
  return std::make_shared<C>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Was exactly the answer I was writing, but you beat me to it.

Comment: This is what I did, but I don't like the fact that resulting `shared_ptr` is copied twice.

Comment: I'n pretty sure copy will optimized out

Comment: With c++11 no copy will be made, in the worst case it will be `moved` out, but more likely return value optimization kicks in.

Comment: Accepting as this is a perfectly valid answer. I don't have any other options it seems